# How can I change the text in the footer when using a template?

Tags: templates, overleaf, footer

I am **completely** new to writing in LaTex so please forgive the basic nature of this question.

I am using a template in Overleaf and there is a footer displaying like this:

[image]

I've searched all the files and I cannot find the text "preprint submitted to Elsevier" anywhere. How can I change this footer? Here are the folders in the project:

[image]

I've checked these folders and searched for the text string shown in the footer but I can't find it. Where is it coming from?

Comment: It will most likely be part of the *class*, which is contained in some `.cls`.

Comment: Ok but where can I find that? The only files in the project are the ones listed in the image above. There isn't a .cls file. I guess it must be loaded from somewhere else, but since I am a beginner I don't know where it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is defined in `cas-common.sty` which is loaded by the `\documentclass{cas-dc}` in your template. To change the text make a new file in your Overleaf project named `cas-common.sty` (you can change the file ending when you rename the file) with the contents of https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/els-cas-templates/cas-common.sty. Change `Preprint~ submitted ~to ~Elsevier` to whatever you want in that file and you will override the default and you will be all set.

For reference I believe this is your template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/elseviers-cas-latex-double-column-template/hhzpymgjmxfk

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much. Yes, that's the template I was using. Can I ask how it was being loaded if it wasn't actually in the project?

Comment: @kandyman Overleaf has a (La)TeX distribution with lots of `.sty` and `.cls` files behind the scenes. For instance when you load `\documentclasss{article}` you don't need to provide `article.cls` as it is already provided by Overleaf. With the above method by adding `cas-common.sty` to your project you are overriding Overleaf's default version of that same document.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation! You made it very clear to me.